QCC Linking issue with Assembly Instructions in QCC Libraries
Building the project using QCC generates the errors shown later in Lib files from compiler itself
Makefile command for Linking
$(OUTPUT): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(QCC) $(QCC_FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES) -Wl,-T,$(LINKER_SCRIPT)

Error in CMD:
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: in function `_start':
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:59: undefined reference to `__preinit_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__preinit_array_start' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:59:(.text+0x34): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:60: undefined reference to `__preinit_array_end'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__preinit_array_end' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:60:(.text+0x38): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:61: undefined reference to `__preinit_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:62: undefined reference to `__preinit_array_end'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:64: undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__fini_array_start' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:64:(.text+0x48): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:65: undefined reference to `__fini_array_end'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__fini_array_end' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:65:(.text+0x4c): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:66: undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:67: undefined reference to `__fini_array_end'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:69: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__init_array_start' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:69:(.text+0x5c): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:70: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//target/qnx7/aarch64le/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__init_array_end' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:70:(.text+0x60): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:71: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
DIR\qos_224\\host\win64\x86_64\usr\bin\aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: /builds/workspace/QOS224-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/startup/aarch64/crt1.S:72: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
cc: C:/Users/ashraf/qos_224//host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld caught signal 1

My question is am I using an incorrect command for linking? or Sth is wrong within the environment?

I think normally the linker script should be defining those symbols. Since you seem to be using a custom one that could be where the error is.

@jester Could I add my Linker script additions needed to the originally defined one ? i.e: keep whatever is used by QCC and add my definitions of the sections and addresses in Makefile?

The manual isn't totally clear, it says "Multiple -T options accumulate." so you could try passing an additional -T with your changes. Otherwise your makefile could apply a patch to a copy of the QCC script.

If you actually need a custom link script (or multiple of them), then you need to be aware that it replaces lds default link script.  Therefore, such a script needs to manually provide all link commands needed, including any related to symbols and external library dependencies introduced automatically by the compiler or implicit in the system libraries.

Although qcc does influence linking, it's not clear to me whether it does so by feeding its own -T option(s) to ld.  If so, then your -T should supplement qcc's, though there might be a question of ordering.  But if qcc is not using -T to influence the linker then your -T is very likely interfering.
